# Parse and access data in JSON by taking vallues from input fields of table : JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

How to parse and access data?
I want the output to be first value of first input field.
The above code gives value as undefined.
The key in json is independent of input field name.

```js
function show() {
  var data = '[';
  $("#table tr").each(function() {
    data += '{"name":"' + $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="text"]').val() +
      '","id":"' + $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="hidden"]').val() +
      '","age":"' + $(this).find('td').eq(1).find('input[type="text"]').val() +
      '","qty":"' + $(this).find('td').eq(2).find('input[type="text"]').val() +
      '","perc":"' + $(this).find('td').eq(3).find('input[type="text"]').val() +
      '","address":"' + $(this).find('td').eq(4).find('input[type="text"]').val() + '"},'
  });
  data += ']';
  var p = data;
  var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p));
  alert(arr[0].name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name" type="text"><input name="id" type="hidden"></td>
    <td><input name="age" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="perc" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="address" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```

Comment: Why `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p));`  - that is the same as `p` which is the same as `data`

Comment: Please post some HTML

Comment: `<table id="table"> <tr> <td><input type="text"></td> <td><input type="hidden"></td> <td><input type="text"></td> <td><input type="text"></td> <td><input type="text"></td> <td><input type="text"></td> <td><input type="text"></td> <tr> </table>`

Comment: Please update the question instead of pasting code in a comment - and do the fields not have names???? My answer relies on them having names

Comment: I updated may answer into a [mcve] now you showed the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, you should not construct string and then convert to json. you can create Javascript object directly.

```
var data = [];
$("#table tr").each(function() {
    data.push({
        name: $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="text"]').val(),
        id: $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="hidden"]').val(),
        age: $(this).find('td').eq(1).find('input[type="text"]').val(),
        qty: $(this).find('td').eq(2).find('input[type="text"]').val(),
        perc: $(this).find('td').eq(3).find('input[type="text"]').val(),
        address: $(this).find('td').eq(4).find('input[type="text"]').val()
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The most elegant is to use a map - especially if you have more than one row

```js
$(function() {
  $("#show").on("click", function() {
    let data = $("#table tr").map(function() {
      return $(":input", this).map(function() {
        return {
          [$(this).attr("name")]: $(this).val()
        };
      }).get();
    }).get();
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" value="Joe"><input name="id" type="hidden" value="ID1"></td>
    <td><input name="age" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="perc" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="address" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" value="Jane"><input name="id" type="hidden" value="ID2"></td>
    <td><input name="age" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="perc" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="address" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="show">Go</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are going to run into all kinds of issues if you try and generate the JSON yourself, I would instead do something like this:

```
var data = [];
$("#table tr").each(function() {
    data.push({
        name: $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="text"]').val(),
        id: $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="hidden"]').val(), 
        age: $(this).find('td').eq(1).find('input[type="text"]').val(),
        qty: $(this).find('td').eq(2).find('input[type="text"]').val(),
        perc: $(this).find('td').eq(3).find('input[type="text"]').val(),
        address: $(this).find('td').eq(4).find('input[type="text"]').val()
    });
});
console.log(data[0].name);
```

Comment: @mplungjan your code 1. has a syntax error and 2. assumes his inputs have a name attribute, which we don't know.

Comment: Fixed the syntax error and I know we do not know, but to keep the `$(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="text"]')` is SO inelegant

Comment: i agree, it's not pretty, but code that works is more elegant than code that doesn't, so without more information I'll keep the inelegant yet more likely to actually work version.

Comment: So now I got relevant HTML, I can prove my version works.